# Pressure and upthrust force

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, buoyancy, lift

What is upthrust force? Is is the pressure difference or just pressure x Area at the bottom of the surface? How does upthrust force change with depth in liquid?

Comment: Have you checked out the similar questions, and answers, already on here? If not, you should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One  often observe that our body feels lighter while taking a swim in the pool.

When drawing water from a well, the bucket feels lighter to us till it is partially or fully immersed in water.

We can say, when immersed in water or any other fluid, the **body experiences a force** from the **downward direction to upward direction** which is responsible for the decrease in its weight.

I think you are calling this force as **upthrust**.

Upthrust  is the force that causes objects to float.

It is the force exerted on an object that is partly or wholly immersed in a fluid and  is caused by **the differences in pressure acting on opposite sides** of an object immersed in a static fluid.

When we dip  an object in a fluid, an upward force is experienced by the object. This force is applied by the fluid on the object which makes it to, rise up and is called the upthrust or Force of **Buoyancy.**

*The value of this force is precisely equal to the amount or weight of the liquid displaced.*